# Laravel/Lumen: Could not establish Memcached connection

Tags: php, laravel, caching, memcached, lumen

I wanted to use caching in my project and thought I'd use Memcached. For that, I installed memcached.

When I output my `phpinfo();` I can see, that the extension exists

[image]

However, when wanting to use it with `Cache::get()`, I get the following error:

> Could not establish Memcached connection.

I have the following values in my .env

```
MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1
MEMCACHED_PORT=11211
```

My php.ini has the following content for memcached

`extension=memcached.so`

What do I need to do, to use memcached now and establish a connection successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure memcached itself is running?

`sudo service memcached status`

If it's off you need to start it.

Comment: Hi, that will probably be it. However, I'm using Mac OS X. Seems like it doesn't know `service`. Also, it doesn't know memcached. (Probably because I haven't put the path's corerctly). What is the equivalent `service` for Mac OS X or would it be just `sudo memcached status` ? Or in other words. Which file would I need for that? I only know about the .so files but these won't be the correct ones for doing that command, right?

Comment: Try running `memcached -d -p 11211 -m 64 -c 1024 -P /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid`

Comment: Unfortunetely I cannot do this. It tells me `memcached: command not found` Where exactly is the memcached executeble located? It is not this one here, right?

`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/memcached.so`

Comment: As you're using XAMPP, according to the docs you should have a panel in the system preferences where you can restart the whole stack?

Comment: Hi, I fixed it by installing memecaced additionally with homebrew. Now it works. Many thanks! Seems like I also had to install memcached, and not only the extension, is this correct?

Comment: Yes thats correct, memcached is a seperate programme. The PHP extension is just to communicate with it.

Answer (score 7):

The Exceptions says:

> Could not establish Memcached connection

So, PHP Memcached "extension" can not "connect" to "Memcached".

Please, try installing:

```
sudo apt-get install memcached
sudo service memcached status
```

And you are ready to go!